# Scheduler with asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback, scheduler, hybrid

I want to use a Scheduler like Telerik Scheduler in my MVC project. The problem is that the Scheduler is a Asp.Net WebForm control. For this reason, I must create a WebForm page in my Mvc project to put the Scheduler control.

When I show the page, it work fine to render the layout of the control but if I try to interact with it; click for change date, change to day view to week view, the control don't change.

I know that postback doesn't work in mvc project but does it work in a WebForm page in a Mvc project? If it doesn't work, it is the reason why when I try to interact with the control, the control don't respond.

I think it's because the postback don't work and the Scheduler use 100 % Databinding where when I change date, the postback don't contain any data that I have changed and for this reason, the control can't change is layout.

Do you have any ideas about postback with WebForm in a MVC project?

What type of designs can I adopt? (Two differents projets: One for my Scheduler with WebForm and another for all the rest of my website in Mvc project)

Are there any other controls that are easy to use with Scheduler?

Does anyone have any tips and tricks when needing both a WebForms control and MVC control in an MVC project?

Answer (score 0):

Hanselman has a [good guide for mixing MVC and WebForms](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) into the same project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try DayPilot Pro (my product, commercial) which has both ASP.NET and MVC versions.

ASP.NET:

- http://www.daypilot.org/

MVC

- http://mvc.daypilot.org/